# PostgreSQL - how to check if my data contains a backslash

Tags: postgresql, backslash

SELECT count(*) FROM table WHERE column ilike '%/%';

gives me the number of values containing "/"

How to do the same for "\"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
SELECT  count(*)
FROM    table
WHERE   column ILIKE '%\\\\%';
```

Answer (score 4):

Excerpt from the [docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-LIKE):

> Note that the backslash already has a special meaning in string literals, so to write a pattern constant that contains a backslash you must write two backslashes in an SQL statement (assuming escape string syntax is used, see Section 4.1.2.1). Thus, writing a pattern that actually matches a literal backslash means writing four backslashes in the statement. You can avoid this by selecting a different escape character with ESCAPE; then a backslash is not special to LIKE anymore. (But it is still special to the string literal parser, so you still need two of them.)

Answer (score 3):

Better yet - don't use like, just use standard position:

```
select count(*)  from table where 0 < position( E'\\' in column );
```

Answer (score 1):

I found on 12.5 I did not need an escape character

```
# select * from t;
  x  
-----
 a/b
 c\d
(2 rows)

# select count(*) from t where 0 < position('/' in x);
 count 
-------
     1
(1 row)

# select count(*) from t where 0 < position('\' in x);
 count 
-------
     1
(1 row)
```

whereas on 9.6 I did.

Bit strange but there you go.
Usefully,

```
position(E'/' in x)
```

worked on both versions.
You need to be careful - E'//' seems to work (i.e.  parses) but does not actually find a slash.

Answer (score 0):

You need `E'\\\\'` because the argument to `LIKE` is a regex and regex escape char is already `\` (e.g `~ E'\\w'` would match any string containing a printable char).

See the [doc](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/interactive/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-STRINGS)